# O que é "cacert.pem"?

Tags: php, libcurl

No código onde uma chamada a API é executada, existe a seguinte linha:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Ao executar o código o seguinte erro é retornado:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate - Code: 60

Logo em seguida, foi adicionado o seguinte código:

```
if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '\cacert.pem');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}
```

O que faz o arquivo "cacert.pem" e porquê ao configurar o "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" para "true" o erro é retornado?

Comment: Não sei se se trata da mesma coisa ou não, mas pelo nome do arquivo me parece que ele deve conter o certificado raiz da autoridade certificadora (CA) que emitiu o certificado de segurança do seu site. Reutilizar de um projeto a outro pode o tornar inválido, como apontado na resposta do Vinícius. Se você comprou seu certificado de segurança no site X, procure nesse mesmo site por mais informações, provavelmente eles disponibilizam o arquivo certo e instruções de como usá-lo corretamente (o meu, StartSSL, chegou a me enviar um e-mail automático com essas instruções na primeira vez que eu errei).

Comment: @mgibsonbr O arquivo possui dados como "Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority". Esse ficheiro é utilizado no SDK/PHP do PayPal, entretanto reutilizei para criar um segundo SDK/PHP para um sistema de faturação online que também utiliza REST+Oauth (porém não possui um SDK/PHP pronto). O projecto é o mesmo, as funcionalidades é que são diferentes. Para o PayPal funcionou, para o sistema de faturação não.

Answer (score 5):

Arquivo `*.pem` é um arquivo contêiner. Geralmente, ele contém o certificado público, mas pode conter também toda cadeia de entidades certificadoras intermediárias e até chaves públicas e privadas, além de entidades certificadoras raízes.

O processo normal de validação de certificados em um servidor web, envolve apenas a validação do certificado do servidor, garantindo que o cliente esta acessando o servidor correto (garantindo, em especial, o não repúdio da informação vinda do servidor).

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` faz com que o certificado do cliente também seja validado. Deste modo, garantimos o não repúdio das informações originadas no cliente.

O que provavelmente esta acontecendo, é que as entidades certificadoras intermediárias do seu certificado estão erradas. Isto pode ocorrer por várias razões, desde arquivo erroneamente especificado, até formatura da assinatura divergir da assinatura do certificado final, ou simplesmente sua entidade certificadora intermediária é inválida (se é ela existir).

Comment: Provavelmente o arquivo ".pem" está errado porque foi aproveitado de outro projecto. Como faço para gerar um novo?

Comment: Se eles forem self-signed, basta utilizar o OpenSSL. Existem vários tutoriais na internet dos comandos a serem executados de acordo com sua necessidade, com uma certificação intermediária ou não. Se a política é de usar certificados assinados por entidades válidas, você deve contactar a entidade de sua preferência e pagar pela geração. Em todo caso, depende das políticas da sua empresa, do uso e da segurança desejada.